# How can I detect IPs of visitors in my Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, ip-address, magento

Is there any solution to find their IPs? There are some reqular daily bounce visitors on our website that I want to block their IPs but I cannot find them. I have the record of online IPs in panel of Magento but cannot allocate them to my Analytics visitor’s behaviors and find bounce IPs.

Comment: Why do you want to block them?

Comment: GA is not the tool for this. Use a log file analyzer. GA can report false spam accesses so you really want to be sure you have an issue. I like piwik though it has recently been renamed. I do not recall the new name. It is free and one of the very best available. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics removed IP address several years ago.  there is no way to identify a user by an ID or the IP address.